# Are these two Java webhook libraries for Actions on Google / Dialogflow functionally equivalent?

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Until recent release of [new Java/Kotlin implementation](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java) for Actions on Google (com.google.actions:actions-on-google:
1.0.2 [Maven coordinate](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.actions/actions-on-google/1.0.2/jar)), we've been (successfully) using [its peer library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/1.28.0/google-api-services-dialogflow/v2/com/google/api/services/dialogflow/v2) (com.google.apis:google-api-services-dialogflow:v2-rev20190209-1.28.0 [Maven coordinates](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-dialogflow/v2-rev20190209-1.28.0/jar)) to implement our Java webhook.

Given that I haven't seen them treated as a replacement of one another, and the latter one still seem to be actively developed, could someone please elaborate on the two libraries so we can set our expectations:

- what are their specific goals and limitations,
- what we should keep in mind if preferring one over the other,
- what feature limitations to expect,
- what is the roadmap for both libraries

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO, please see the guidance in the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not functionally the same.

The Dialogflow fulfillment library is for any Dialogflow agent. This processes the JSON and helps generate the response including text and basic responses.

The AoG library is for an Action. This too processes the JSON and generates responses.

While this may seem the same, there are several differences as Actions on Google has additional features that are not in Dialogflow itself:

- Account linking including Google Sign-In is available for AoG
- Permissions such as getting the user's location is available for AoG
- Additional rich responses like a media player is available for AoG

Developers who are only building an Action with Dialogflow should use the AoG library to take advantage of these platform-exclusive features. For a more generic Dialogflow agent, you can use the Dialogflow fulfillment library to get cross-platform capabilities.